# using fread on triple pointer in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, fread

I know how to read a file into a 2d array using for loops to direct where you are storing the data in C, but what I am interested in is if you can use one fread() call to do this.  That is, can I do something like this:

```
int A[5][5];
fread(&A, sizeof(int), 25, filePtr);
```

I am getting seg faults when I tried this so right now so I am wonder if this can be done at all.

EDIT:
Alright, I guess using fread this way isn't really my problem.  My problem is that I have to call fread from within a function and A is defined outside of that function.

```
func(int size, int ***A)
{
  fread(*A, sizeof(int), size*size, filePtr);
}

main
{
  int A[n][n];
  func(n, &A);
}
```

So my problem is that my call to fread still seg faults and I HAVE to use a triple pointer for my function prototype.  I tried just A (instead of *A) for fun but still got the same seg fault.  It looks like I'm just overlooking something with pointers.

Comment: Yeah it compiles.  That address is stored somewhere so taking the address of that value is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that of contiguous memory.  It's actually very straight forward when you realize that fread is only set up to take single pointers.  Therefore it can only take 1-d arrays.  However, if your 2-d array is represented in memory contiguously it is analogous to a 1-d array.  Therefore, just pass fread a pointer to the first element in your 2-d array, it will start looping through it as if it is a 1-d array and all will be well.

So just make sure your 2-d array is contiguously assigned and you should be fine.

```
malloc(n*n *sizeof(int))
```

instead of mallocing in a for loop for each row.

Answer (score 2):

`A` is already a pointer to the array. `&A` is a pointer to this pointer, which is not what you want. All you need to do is replace `&A` with `A`.

Comment: Yeah, you are definitely right.  Looks like my problem is with passing A to a function as it turns out, not with the call to fread.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to think of arrays in C is synonymous with pointers except on one front: you can't change the address they reference like a regular pointer. For example:

```
int A[5][5];
int *aptr = A;  // notice no &

aptr += 2; // works fine.
A += 2;    // does NOT compile.
```

Similarly this...

```
int A[5][5];
fread(A, sizeof(int), 25, filePtr); // again, note no &
```

and this...

```
int A[5][5];
int *aptr = A;
fread(aptr, sizeof(int), 25, filePtr); // no & here either.
```

both end up sending the same address to `fread()`.

Again, in C, think of arrays as pointers who's "value" (the memory address) you cannot change. All other aspects of them are virtually the same. It will save you a LOT of headache later on.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I do grasp this bit of pointer meaning.  It is when pointers *appear* to not behave like that when I get confused.  Right now I'm trying to correct my thinking so they no longer appear that way.

Comment: Work with it a ton more, it will gel.